# round off decimal points in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, decimal, tofixed

I'm trying to round off the decimal. Below are the scenarios

```
Entered Value - 56.6
Round off Value - 57

Entered Value - 56.7
Round off Value - 57

Entered Value - 56.8
Round off Value - 57
```

But same thing when i try to round of `56.3/56.2/56.4`, same value is displaying.

When i try `56.1` to `56.4`, i'm getting the same value itself. But when i try from `56.5` to `56.9` value is rounding off to `57`

```
Entered Value - 56.3
Round off Value - 56.3
Expected Value - 57
```

i've tried below code to round of

```
parseFloat(value).toFixed();
Math.round(value)
```

How to actually execute all the scenarios of to round off?

Comment: `Math.round(56.2)`

Comment: I'm confused what your actual expected outcome is. If `Math.round()` is not working for you, what output do you want/expect from which input?

Comment: It isn't clear what value you expect based on your examples. Are you trying to round down to the nearest integer? If so, try `Math.floor()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.round()` rounds to the nearest integer. So it rounds down for fractions below `.5`, and rounds up for fractions above `.5`.

If you always want to round up, use `Math.ceil()`.

```js
value = 56.3;
console.log(Math.ceil(value));
```